# iOS Swift generic function tot handle universal link

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Hi I have a universal link to implement in my app. I have created a generic function to achieve that, code below

```
  fileprivate func gotoVC<T>(viewcontroller:T,storyBoard: UIStoryboard) {
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "\(T.self)")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
  }
```

This works perfect, but to some view controllers I have to pass ids (ex: id to call the API, like product ID)

Can anyone help me to send those ids to the view controllers using this method ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to declare a protocol (let's call it `ApiIdHolder`) that has an `apiId` property, then have your destination view controllers implement that protocol. Now, add the following line to your `gotoVC()` implementation, right after the `instantiate(withIdentifier:)` call:

```
(vc as? ApiIdHolder)?.apiId = apiId
```

or, less tersely,

```
if let apiIdHolder = vc as? ApiIdHolder {
    apiIdHolder.apiId = apiId
}
```

The fact that this is in a generic function is irrelevant; it'll work in any function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps

try declaring the ids like:

```
let ID = "ID"
```

then to access:

```
ClassNameThatContainsDeclaredID().nameOfIDVariable
```

If it do not work, try creating an universal ID, declare the id as above:

```
let ID = "ID"
```

But do not do this in any class! Do it outside classes, in the beginning of your code, after import xxxxx and before class declaration. Then you may just refer the id itself because you should have created an universal constant :) (search about singletons)

If none of these options work, you may use UserDefaults that saves forever (while the app is installed) your ID:

Just do this:

```
let ID = "ID"
UserDefaults.standard.set(ID, forKey: "ID1")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

and access in other views with this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "ID1") //Should contain the ID1 value
```

I just gave you three ways to make a universal constant/variable, hope it helps!!

Comment: That's not even remotely an answer to the question that OP was asking.